# how can i create a CSR with specific Configuration using python

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, private-key, csr

i need to create a CSR with specific configuration using python

this is my configuration :

```
oid_section = OIDs
[ OIDs ]
certificateTemplateName= 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
emailAddress        = test@gmail.com
req_extensions          = v3_req
x509_extensions         = v3_ca
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn


[ dn ]
C=SA
OU=3111111117 
O=shesh
CN = tat-1


[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment

[req_ext]
certificateTemplateName = ASN1:PRINTABLESTRING:PREZATCA-Code-Signing
subjectAltName = dirName:alt_names


[alt_names]
SN=1-Device|2-234|3-mohamm
UID=30000000000000003
title=1000
registeredAddress=Zatca 12
businessCategory=Technology
```

i can create a CSR with this configuration using OpenSSL

but i need to Create a CSR with this configuration using Python.

i tried to do it using this code:

```py
from OpenSSL.SSL import FILETYPE_PEM
from OpenSSL.crypto import dump_certificate_request, dump_privatekey,dump_publickey, PKey, TYPE_DSA, X509Req
 

# create public/private key
key = PKey()
key.generate_key(TYPE_DSA,1028)

print(key.to_cryptography_key())

# Generate CSR
req = X509Req()
req.get_subject().CN = 'localhost'
req.get_subject().O = 'XYZ Widgets Inc'
req.get_subject().OU = 'IT Department'
req.get_subject().L = 'Seattle'
req.get_subject().ST = 'Washington'
req.get_subject().C = 'US'
req.get_subject().emailAddress = 'e@example.com'
req.set_pubkey(key)
req.sign(key, 'sha256')

with open("csr_testo.pem", 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(dump_certificate_request(FILETYPE_PEM, req))

with open("Private_key_testo.pem", 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(dump_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, key))

with open("public_key_testo.pem", 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(dump_publickey(FILETYPE_PEM, key))
```

but it does not take all of my configuration.

```
[alt_names]
SN=1-Device|2-234|3-mohamm
UID=30000000000000003
title=1000
registeredAddress=Zatca 12
businessCategory=Technology
```

these configurations are very important to include them in the CSR

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code

```
from cryptography import x509
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
    from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID, ExtensionOID
    
    # Generate a private key
    private_key = dsa.generate_private_key(key_size=2048)
    
    # Set the subject name and add extensions
    subject = x509.Name([
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, "SA"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, "shesh"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME, "3111111117"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, "tat-1"),
    ])
    extensions = [
        x509.BasicConstraints(ca=False, path_length=None),
        x509.KeyUsage(digital_signature=True, key_encipherment=True, content_commitment=False, data_encipherment=False, key_agreement=False, encipher_only=False, decipher_only=False),
        x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
            x509.DirectoryName(x509.Name([
                x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.SERIAL_NUMBER, "1-Device|2-234|3-mohamm"),
                x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.USER_ID, "30000000000000003"),
                x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.TITLE, "1000"),
                x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.REGISTERED_ADDRESS, "Zatca 12"),
                x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.BUSINESS_CATEGORY, "Technology"),
            ]))
        ]),
        x509.CertificatePolicies([
            x509.PolicyInformation(x509.ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2"), [])
        ])
    ]
    
    # Generate the CSR
    csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(subject).add_extensions(extensions).sign(private_key, hashes.SHA256())
    
    # Save the CSR and private key to files
    with open("csr_testo.pem", "wb") as f:
        f.write(csr.public_bytes(encoding=x509.Encoding.PEM))
    
    with open("private_key_testo.pem", "wb") as f:
        f.write(private_key.private_bytes(encoding=x509.Encoding.PEM, format=x509.PrivateFormat.PKCS8, encryption_algorithm=x509.NoEncryption()))
```